# Extracting Data from CSV Files Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing, firewall

I've got a syslog server dumping logs from our firewall appliance to CSV files. I'm taking that csv file, and want to pull out certain pieces of data like source and destination IP addresses in the log so I can run further analysis on them later.

This is an example of a single record from the source file. Notice how the IP addresses contained within the data are prefixed with either "src_ip", "dst_ip", "tran_src_ip" or "tran_dest_ip". 
Note: I've edited the IP addresses to mask them.

> 2018-07-01 14:48:47,Local7.Info,192.168.1.00,device="SFW" date=2018-07-01 time=14:48:39 timezone="PDT" device_name="XG" device_id=00000000000000 log_id=010101600001 log_type="Firewall" log_component="Firewall Rule" log_subtype="Allowed" status="Allow" priority=Information duration=11 fw_rule_id=3 policy_type=3 user_name="" user_gp="" iap=0 ips_policy_id=0 appfilter_policy_id=0 application="Secure Socket Layer Protocol" application_risk=1 application_technology="Network Protocol" application_category="Infrastructure" in_interface="Port2" out_interface="Port1" src_mac=00: 0:00: 0:00: 0 src_ip=75.148.000.000 src_country_code=USA dst_ip=23.24.000.000 dst_country_code=USA protocol="TCP" src_port=55000 dst_port=443 sent_pkts=7  recv_pkts=6 sent_bytes=1369 recv_bytes=918 tran_src_ip=192.168.000.000 tran_src_port=0 tran_dst_ip=192.168.000.000 tran_dst_port=0 srczonetype="WAN" srczone="WAN" dstzonetype="LOCAL" dstzone="LOCAL" dir_disp="" connevent="Stop" connid="1782869248" vconnid="" hb_health="No Heartbeat" message="" appresolvedby="Signature"

I've been able to write a script that can pull IP addresses out of the entire CSV file, but it doesn't specify if it's the src_ip or dst_ip, etc. I'd like to be able to create a script that can take the data from a CSV file, and then create a new CSV file with columns that contain the  src_ip, dest_ip, etc.

My code is below:

```
$input_path = ‘c:\powershell_work\data.csv’
$output_file = ‘c:\powershell_work\output-file.csv’
$regex = ‘\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b’

$ipaddresses = select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | 
% { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } | out-file $output_file -append
```

Comment: Is that _exactly_ how the file appears to you? That is not really a csv. It has 4 columns, with no headers the last of which contains newlines

Comment: I added spaces in my post so that they would be formatted as code, but I can see now that it messed it up. I'll edit the OP so that it won't contain the spaces for my example input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$regex = '\b(\w+)=(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)'

Select-String -LiteralPath $input_path -AllMatches -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = New-Object pscustomobject
    foreach ($match in $_.Matches) {
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -NotePropertyName $match.Groups[1].Value -NotePropertyValue $match.Groups[2].Value
    }
    $obj
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $output_file
```

**EDIT by LotPings**

Sample output of your above updated input (before the `Export-Csv` call):

```
src_ip         dst_ip        tran_src_ip     tran_dst_ip
------         ------        -----------     -----------
75.148.000.000 23.24.000.000 192.168.000.000 192.168.000.000
```

---

**To extract a specifiable set of properties by *name***:

```
# Use a regex that matches all key-value pairs.
$regex = '\b(\w+)=([^ ]+)'

Select-String -LiteralPath $input_path -AllMatches -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = New-Object pscustomobject
    foreach ($match in $_.Matches) {
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -NotePropertyName $match.Groups[1].Value -NotePropertyValue $match.Groups[2].Value
    }
    $obj
} | Select-Object *_ip, srczone, src_country_code, dstzone, dst_country_code | 
     Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $output_file
```

Note that this first creates an object with *all* input properties and *then* selects only those of interest via `Select-Object`, which is somewhat inefficient, but keeps the command conceptually simple and allows you to easily determine the extraction *order*.

Comment: Awesome that worked! Is there a way we can further parse this to pull out all of the information into additional columns? Like pulling out the Country_Code, srzzone, dstzone, etc.

Comment: @FrameWorkTeam: Glad to hear it; as for pulling out other fields: please see my update.